# Diferenças entre Criteria e HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

Nas apostilas que li e tutoriais que acompanhei o `Criteria` é mais utilizado, porém eu me identifiquei mais com `HQL`. Mas tenho a seguinte dúvida, tudo que é feito com `Criteria` é possível fazer com `HQL`?

Exemplo HQL:

```
//Select * from Suspensao
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Suspensao.listar", query = "SELECT suspensao FROM Suspensao suspensao") })
```

E depois no DAO:

```
Query consulta = sessao.getNamedQuery("Suspensao.listar");
            lista = consulta.list();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salvo raras exceções, tudo o que você faz com um consegue também fazer com o outro. Acho que a diferença está em como cada um deles funciona. Alguns detalhes interessantes para levar em consideração na hora da sua escolha:

- Criteria é a melhor escolha para queries dinâmicas, quando você lida com muitos parâmetros opcionais, o que geralmente acontece em qualquer sistema web. É muito mais fácil ordenar dinâmicamente ou adicionar/remover uma restrição baseada em um parâmetro. Paginar com Criteria também é muito mais fácil.
- HQL é mais interessante para queries estáticas. HQL tende gerar um código menor, mais claro e fácil de entender. Além disso você pode transformar essas hql queries em Named queries, o que traz um certo ganho de desempenho.

Creio que optar por usar somente um deles é abrir mão de uma parte interessante das ferramentas que o Hibernate te oferece. Considere usar os dois, cada um para o tipo de pesquisa que você estiver montando no momento.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela explicação